# Apache / Zend Framework - Error Log - Page Not found

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, apache2

This one is a little confusing to me.

I'm running a LAMP server with Zend Framework.   I've spent a lot of time going over my error logs to try and clean-up any programming errors/bugs.

Most of my specific site errors are done but I looked into my general Apache error log:

```
/var/log/apache2/error.log
```

And I'm seeing a lot, almost constant, errors for "File does not exist" like the following (simplified for brevity):

```
[date] [error] [client #:#:#:#] File does not exist: /var/www/sites/[website folder]/public/explore
[date] [error] [client #:#:#:#] File does not exist: /var/www/sites/[website folder]/public/where-to-buy
[date] [error] [client #:#:#:#] File does not exist: /var/www/sites/[website folder]/public/products
```

And so on. These folders do not exist because all requests are suppose to be redirected into the index.php file and handled by Zend Framework.   The actual controllers and actions exist, such that anyone going to:

```
http://www.example.com/explore
```

or

```
http://www.example.com/where-to-buy/
```

will get the correct page via Zend Framework.

But I'm not understanding why all these errors are occuring?

If figure it might have something to do with the .htaccess file that redirects most requests (excluding style sheets, documents, images, etc) to the index.php script.  This is what mine looks like:

```
RewriteEngine On
# make sure all requests go to 'www' sub-domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Zend Framework, redirect requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Is Apache trying to resolve the request via an actual directory first and then passing the request to index.php?  Which causes the error request?

I'm also not sure why this is getting dumped into the default error log, instead of the error log or the specific site.  In other words, I have error logs for each domain such as "example.com_error.log".  That might be another indication to the issue.  It might be a sequence thing as "error.log" is tired to a "default" site.

Thanks for any insight!
Fozzy

Comment: It can be a problem with the htaccess. Have you tried to merge the two main condition? I mean the fact that all the request is redirected to the www version and the one which will redirect to index.php?

Comment: the fact this is going to the default log is effectively a good hint on the problem, check the related access.log. Maybe some requests made on a DNS name not handled in your virtualhost or by web clients not using HTTP 1/1 (so with no host header)

Comment: One interesting bit of info is that there are also referral links in the log and they're coming from my website: www.example.com.

Comment: As suggested by regilero (why I didn't think about doing this, I don't know), I looked into the access logs at the same IP/timestamp.  It doesn't appear they're accessing anything out of the ordinary.  It also appears that it was happening (a lot) on one day.   For now, I'll just have to keep an eye on it to see if it keeps happening.  As per Aurelio's suggestion, there might be something going on with my htaccess redirects.  I've not seen this happening since.  Maybe I did something odd for that one given day.

Comment: Do you have fixed it? it would be helpful for me :)

Comment: I have grown a little in understanding Apache logs and I've learned to compare error and access logs to help troubleshoot issues.  I believe that has cleared up most of my issues.

Comment: Just to be certain... you do have apache's mod_rewrite module enabled right?

Comment: @BryanMoyles Yes.  What I found since the time I wrote this question was that the folders being checked were automatic scripts that where accessing the site via the IP address and not a domain name.  The IP address was still using Apache's default configuration so it wasn't running off zend framework.

Comment: please add that as an answer. this will also help getting this question from the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Regilero:

> the fact this is going to the default log is effectively a good hint
>   on the problem, check the related access.log. Maybe some requests made
>   on a DNS name not handled in your virtualhost or by web clients not
>   using HTTP 1/1 (so with no host header) – regilero Oct 19 '11 at 22:52

I was able to compare the access.log with the error.log to investigate my issues.

It was awhile ago but I believe the issue was due to some script going directly to the server via an IP address and trying to use the directory structure from one of the virtually hosted domains.